# How to Create a 2D array of characters in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

```
char [][]grid1 = {{'O','O','O','O','O','O'},
                  {'O','O','X','X','O','O'},
                  {'O','O','O','O','X','O'},
                  {'O','O','O','O','O','X'},
                };
```

How will I create a 2D char array shown above.
I've done using **scan.next()**, which creates an array of Strings and not char as **next()** takes input as String.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = scan.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your outer loop do `String a = scan.next()`. In your inner loop do `int j = 0; j < a.length; j++`. Then something like `grid[i][j] = a.charAt(j);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by below some way:

1) Convert string to character array and get first one.

```
scan.next().toCharArray()[0]
```

2) Or find a character at 0th position of string input.

```
scan.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can take input as a string and take the first character of it

```
       scan.next().charAt(0);
```